# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NO_FORMAT when tunning maven surefire junit tests

Tags: java, maven, junit, log4j, surefire

When trying to run junit tests from maven (maven surefire plugin) I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NO_FORMAT
```

This error seems to come from any call to my log4j logger. So when I have a class with a log4j class variable `log`, like:

```
public class SomeClass {

    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SomeClass.class);

    ....
}
```

then a call to

```
log.info(String msg);
```

results in the above error. I tried to make sure that the basic configuration is setup when running the junit tests, such as

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    BasicConfigurator.configure();
    someclass = new SomeClass();
}
```

but that does not solve this problem. Removing all the `log` calls solves the problem, but that is not a very nice solution.

Any idea why this problem occur? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading/downgrading your log4j dependency.

Comment: I tried various log4j versions, namely 1.2.1,,1.2.4, 1.2.9, 1.2.12, 1.2.16, 1.2.17. None of those solves this problem. I also updated the junit lib to 4.11, but also this does not solve it. I'm using Maven 3.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this gonna helps, but I will try to check is to see if you have more than one Log4j dependencies in your classpath i.e I will run `mvn dependency:tree` and maybe output it to a temporary file e.g. `mvn dependency:tree > deps.txt` and analyze my dependencies from then on.

Answer (score 0):

To me the problem was that I had activated an arquillian profile as well. Make sure you only activate the right one to run the maven tests :-)